# Running OpenCV-4.0.0 C++ function

Tags: c++, c, go, cgo

I have created a C API which exposes the functionality of C++ code. Here is the code for `opencv_test.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC void OpenVideo(char *filename);

#undef EXTERNC
```

Code for `opencv_test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "opencv_test.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void OpenVideo(char *filename){
    VideoCapture cap(filename);
    Mat Uframe;
    int frameCount = 0;

    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        cout<<"Cannot open video file!";
        return;
    }

    namedWindow("Video");
    while(++frameCount){

        bool success = cap.read(Uframe);

        if(!success){
            cout<<frameCount<<" frames read";
            break;      
        }

        imshow("Video", Uframe);
        waitKey(1);

    }

}
```

And finally, for `opencvTest.go`:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv_test.h"
*/
import "C"

func main(){

    theFilename := "DRŽAVNI POSAO [HQ] - Ep.323 Dan žena (07.03.2014.).avi"
    C.OpenVideo(C.CString(theFilename))
}
```

And the error I am getting is the following:

---

> command-line-arguments /tmp/go-build823465636/b001/_x002.o: In
>   function "_cgo_dcf5d601f507_Cfunc_OpenVideo":
>   /tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:48: undefined reference to `OpenVideo'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

---

Now I am not sure if I have to run any kind of special commands or something, I have read that just by importing **"C"** pseudo-package, my `.go` file will be build with `cgo`. So, if I have included my custom-made `.h` file, and the project is built using `cgo`, how come I get *undefined reference to a function* error?

EDIT:

Here is the whole output when running `go build -x opencvTest.go` command:

> WORK=/tmp/go-build568047770
>
> mkdir -p $WORK/b001/
>
> cd /home/stefan/Desktop/GoLang
>
> CGO_LDFLAGS='"-L/usr/local/lib" "-lopencv_core" "-lopencv_video"
>   "-lopencv_videoio" "-lopencv_highgui" "-L/usr/local/lib"
>   "-lopencv_core" "-lopencv_video" "-lopencv_videoio"
>   "-lopencv_highgui"' /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir
>   $WORK/b001/ -importpath command-line-arguments -- -I/usr/local/include
>   -I $WORK/b001/ -g -O2 ./opencvTest.go
>
> cd $WORK
>
> gcc -fno-caret-diagnostics -c -x c - || true
>
> gcc -Qunused-arguments -c -x c - || true
>
> gcc -fdebug-prefix-map=a=b -c -x c - || true
>
> gcc -gno-record-gcc-switches -c -x c - || true
>
> cd $WORK/b001
>
> TERM='dumb' gcc -I /home/stefan/Desktop/GoLang -fPIC -m64 -pthread
>   -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
>
> -I/usr/local/include -I ./ -g -O2 -o ./_x001.o -c _cgo_export.c TERM='dumb' gcc -I /home/stefan/Desktop/GoLang -fPIC -m64 -pthread
>   -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
>
> -I/usr/local/include -I ./ -g -O2 -o ./_x002.o -c opencvTest.cgo2.c TERM='dumb' gcc -I /home/stefan/Desktop/GoLang -fPIC -m64 -pthread
>   -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
>
> -I/usr/local/include -I ./ -g -O2 -o ./_cgo_main.o -c _cgo_main.c cd /home/stefan/Desktop/GoLang TERM='dumb' gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread
>   -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -o $WORK/b001/*cgo*.o  $WORK/b001/_cgo_main.o $WORK/b001/_x001.o $WORK/b001/_x002.o -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core
>   -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui
>
> command-line-arguments /tmp/go-build568047770/b001/_x002.o: In
>   function `_cgo_dcf5d601f507_Cfunc_OpenVideo':
>   /tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:48: undefined reference to`OpenVideo'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I'm not seeing anything there about `opencv_test.cpp` being compiled, or the result being linked to your golang program.  I'm not sure how this is supposed to work on the golang side, but that's what appears to be missing.

Comment: You are right. Any idea why that is happening? I am new to GoLang.